# Unfortunately application has stopped and Java Fatal Exception Main

Tags: java, android

Hi Trying to make a calculator but struck from 3 days at single problem. When I click equal to button application stops working. Read many posts but can't find the solution so at last asking here.

Xml Code

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main" tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="1"
        android:id="@+id/one"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="156dp" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="2"
        android:id="@+id/two"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/one"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="3"
        android:id="@+id/three"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/two"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="4"
        android:id="@+id/four"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/one"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/one" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="5"
        android:id="@+id/five"
        android:layout_above="@+id/seven"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="6"
        android:id="@+id/six"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/three"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/three" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="7"
        android:id="@+id/seven"
        android:layout_marginTop="44dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/four"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    <Button
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="8"
        android:id="@+id/eight"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/seven"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/five"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/five"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/five"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/five" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="9"
        android:id="@+id/nine"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/eight"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/six"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/six" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="0"
        android:id="@+id/zero"
        android:layout_below="@+id/eight"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="47dp" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Clear"
        android:id="@+id/clear"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/zero"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="="
        android:id="@+id/equals"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/zero"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

    <Button
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="+"
        android:id="@+id/add"
        android:layout_marginBottom="29dp"
        android:layout_above="@+id/two"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/one"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/one" />

    <Button
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/sub"
        android:text="-"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/add"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/two"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/two" />

    <Button
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="x"
        android:id="@+id/mul"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/sub"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/three"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/three" />

    <Button
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="/"
        android:id="@+id/div"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/mul"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="Large Text"
        android:id="@+id/out"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

```
  package com.example.parth.calculator;

  import android.os.Bundle;
  import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
  import android.view.Menu;
  import android.view.MenuItem;
  import android.widget.Button;
  import android.widget.TextView;
  import android.view.View;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
public static int a,b,c,d,h,f,u,n,x;
public  TextView car;
public static int digit() {
    if ( a==0 && b == 0 && c == 0 && d == 0 ){

        d = x ;
    } else if (a==0 && b == 0 && c == 0 && d != 0 ){
        c = d ;
        d = x ;
    } else if (a==0 && b == 0 && c != 0 && d != 0 ){

        b = c;
        c= d ;
        d =x ;

    }else if (a==0 && b != 0 && c != 0 && d != 0 ) {

        a = b;
        b = c;
        c = d;
        d = x;

    }

    // else not defined.
    else{
        d = 0;
    }
    n = 1000*a + 100*b + 10*c + d ;

  return n;


}
//method digit end.


public static int func(){
    if (f == 1 ){

        h += n;
    return h ;
    }

    else if(f == 2){

        h -=n;

        return h ;

    }
    else if(f == 3){

        h *= n;

        return h ;

    }



    else if(f == 4){

        h /= n;

        return h ;

    }

    else {

        h = n;
        return h ;

    }

}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


Button one, two, three, four, five, six, seven, eight, nine, zero,                             

equals, add, sub, mul, div;

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    one = (Button) findViewById(R.id.one);
    two = (Button) findViewById(R.id.two);
    three = (Button) findViewById(R.id.three);
    four = (Button) findViewById(R.id.four);
    five = (Button) findViewById(R.id.five);
    six = (Button) findViewById(R.id.six);
    seven = (Button) findViewById(R.id.seven);
    eight = (Button) findViewById(R.id.eight);
    nine = (Button) findViewById(R.id.nine);
    zero = (Button) findViewById(R.id.zero);
    equals = (Button) findViewById(R.id.equals);
    add = (Button) findViewById(R.id.add);
    sub = (Button) findViewById(R.id.sub);
    mul = (Button) findViewById(R.id.mul);
    div = (Button) findViewById(R.id.div);

    car = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.out);



    // Methods for click button start

    add.setOnClickListener(
            new Button.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    f = 1;
                }
            }
    );


    sub.setOnClickListener(
            new Button.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    f = 2;
                }
            }
    );


    mul.setOnClickListener(
            new Button.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    f = 3;

                }
            }
    );


    div.setOnClickListener(
            new Button.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    f = 4;
                }
            }
    );

    one.setOnClickListener(
            new Button.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    x = 1;
                    digit();
                    func();
                }
            }
    );


    two.setOnClickListener(
            new Button.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {
                  x = 2;
                    digit();
                    func();

                }
            }
    );


    three.setOnClickListener(
            new Button.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    x = 3;

                    digit();
                    func();
                }
            }
    );


    four.setOnClickListener(
            new Button.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    x = 4;

                    digit();
                    func();

                }
            }
    );


    five.setOnClickListener(
            new Button.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {
                x = 5;
                    digit();
                    func();

                }
            }
    );


    six.setOnClickListener(
            new Button.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {
                  x = 6;
                    digit();
                    func();

                }
            }
    );


    seven.setOnClickListener(
            new Button.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    x = 7 ;
                    digit();
                    func();

                }
            }
    );


    eight.setOnClickListener(
            new Button.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    x = 8;
                    digit();
                    func();


                }
            }
    );

    nine.setOnClickListener(
            new Button.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {
               x = 9;
                    digit();
                    func();

                }
            }
    );


    zero.setOnClickListener(
            new Button.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    x= 0;
                    digit();
                    func();



                }
            }
    );


    // Methods for click button end


           // Methods for function start




    //extra

    equals.setOnClickListener(
            new Button.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    car.setText(h);
                }
            }
    );

}
```

Logcat>

```
10-25 17:34:49.592 26980-26980/? I/SELinux: Function: selinux_android_load_priority , priority [2] , priority version is VE=SEPF_SM-E700H_4.4.4_A046
10-25 17:34:49.592 26980-26980/? E/SELinux: [DEBUG] get_category: variable seinfocat: default sensitivity: NULL, cateogry: NULL
10-25 17:34:49.592 26980-26980/? E/dalvikvm: >>>>> Normal User
10-25 17:34:49.592 26980-26980/? E/dalvikvm: >>>>> com.example.parth.calculator [ userId:0 | appId:10263 ]
10-25 17:34:49.592 26980-26980/? E/SELinux: [DEBUG] get_category: variable seinfocat: default sensitivity: NULL, cateogry: NULL
10-25 17:34:49.592 26980-26980/? I/libpersona: KNOX_SDCARD checking this for 10263
10-25 17:34:49.592 26980-26980/? I/libpersona: KNOX_SDCARD not a persona
10-25 17:34:49.602 26980-26980/? D/dalvikvm: Late-enabling CheckJNI
10-25 17:34:49.612 26980-26980/? D/TimaKeyStoreProvider: in addTimaSignatureService
10-25 17:34:49.612 26980-26980/? D/TimaKeyStoreProvider: Cannot add TimaSignature Service, License check Failed
10-25 17:34:49.612 26980-26980/? D/ActivityThread: Added TimaKesytore provider
10-25 17:34:49.702 26980-26980/? W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Landroid/view/SearchEvent;)
10-25 17:34:49.702 26980-26980/? I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.view.Window$Callback.onSearchRequested, referenced from method android.support.v7.internal.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.onSearchRequested
10-25 17:34:49.702 26980-26980/? W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve interface method 17896: Landroid/view/Window$Callback;.onSearchRequested (Landroid/view/SearchEvent;)Z
10-25 17:34:49.702 26980-26980/? D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x72 at 0x0002
10-25 17:34:49.702 26980-26980/? I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.view.Window$Callback.onWindowStartingActionMode, referenced from method android.support.v7.internal.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.onWindowStartingActionMode
10-25 17:34:49.702 26980-26980/? W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve interface method 17900: Landroid/view/Window$Callback;.onWindowStartingActionMode (Landroid/view/ActionMode$Callback;I)Landroid/view/ActionMode;
10-25 17:34:49.702 26980-26980/? D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x72 at 0x0002
10-25 17:34:49.732 26980-26980/? I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.content.res.TypedArray.getChangingConfigurations, referenced from method android.support.v7.internal.widget.TintTypedArray.getChangingConfigurations
10-25 17:34:49.732 26980-26980/? W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 421: Landroid/content/res/TypedArray;.getChangingConfigurations ()I
10-25 17:34:49.742 26980-26980/? D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0002
10-25 17:34:49.742 26980-26980/? I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.content.res.TypedArray.getType, referenced from method android.support.v7.internal.widget.TintTypedArray.getType
10-25 17:34:49.742 26980-26980/? W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 443: Landroid/content/res/TypedArray;.getType (I)I
10-25 17:34:49.742 26980-26980/? D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0002
10-25 17:34:49.782 26980-26980/? D/Activity: #1 setTransGradationModeColor false
10-25 17:34:49.832 26980-26980/? I/Adreno-EGL: <qeglDrvAPI_eglInitialize:410>: EGL 1.4 QUALCOMM build:  ()
10-25 17:34:49.832 26980-26980/? I/Adreno-EGL: OpenGL ES Shader Compiler Version: E031.24.02.07
10-25 17:34:49.832 26980-26980/? I/Adreno-EGL: Build Date: 11/29/14 Sat
10-25 17:34:49.832 26980-26980/? I/Adreno-EGL: Local Branch: 
10-25 17:34:49.832 26980-26980/? I/Adreno-EGL: Remote Branch: 
10-25 17:34:49.832 26980-26980/? I/Adreno-EGL: Local Patches: 
10-25 17:34:49.832 26980-26980/? I/Adreno-EGL: Reconstruct Branch: 
10-25 17:34:49.852 26980-26980/? D/OpenGLRenderer: Enabling debug mode 0
10-25 17:34:50.892 26980-26980/? D/ViewRootImpl: ViewPostImeInputStage ACTION_DOWN
10-25 17:34:51.212 26980-26980/? D/ViewRootImpl: ViewPostImeInputStage ACTION_DOWN
10-25 17:34:51.432 26980-26980/? D/ViewRootImpl: ViewPostImeInputStage ACTION_DOWN
10-25 17:34:51.562 26980-26980/? W/ResourceType: No package identifier when getting value for resource number 0x00000001
10-25 17:34:51.562 26980-26980/? D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
10-25 17:34:51.562 26980-26980/? W/dalvikvm: threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41bcbda0)
10-25 17:34:51.562 26980-26980/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-25 17:34:51.562 26980-26980/? E/AndroidRuntime: Process: com.example.parth.calculator, PID: 26980
10-25 17:34:51.562 26980-26980/? E/AndroidRuntime: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x1
10-25 17:34:51.562 26980-26980/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.content.res.Resources.getText(Resources.java:1407)
10-25 17:34:51.562 26980-26980/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:5131)
10-25 17:34:51.562 26980-26980/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.example.parth.calculator.MainActivity$5.onClick(MainActivity.java:219)
10-25 17:34:51.562 26980-26980/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4881)
10-25 17:34:51.562 26980-26980/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19592)
10-25 17:34:51.562 26980-26980/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
10-25 17:34:51.562 26980-26980/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
10-25 17:34:51.562 26980-26980/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)
10-25 17:34:51.562 26980-26980/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5756)
10-25 17:34:51.562 26980-26980/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-25 17:34:51.562 26980-26980/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
10-25 17:34:51.562 26980-26980/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1291)
10-25 17:34:51.562 26980-26980/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1107)
10-25 17:34:51.562 26980-26980/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
10-25 17:34:53.152 26980-26980/? I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 26980 SIG: 9
```

Comment: What do you mean by 'application stops working'? Do you get an error message?

Comment: And please take a minute to format your question in a way that makes it readable. You want us to help; so you want to spend the time to make that easier for us! And side note on code quality: giving your variables single character names is sorry, plain bullsh**. Give them names that tell what they are.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID

Because of following line:

```
car.setText(h);
```

`h` is `int` which is not valid  resource ID.show `int` in `TextView` as:

```
 car.setText(String.valueOf(h));
```

Comment: if ( a==0 && b == 0 && c == 0 && d == 0 ){

        d = x ;
    } else if (a==0 && b == 0 && c == 0 && d != 0 ){
        c = d ;
        d = x ;
    } else if (a==0 && b == 0 && c != 0 && d != 0 ){

        b = c;
        c= d ;
        d =x ;

    }else if (a==0 && b != 0 && c != 0 && d != 0 ) {

        a = b;
        b = c;
        c = d;
        d = x;

    }

Comment: could you also see this it says me that d != 0  and c != 0 && d != 0  is always true.